# Convert XML URL to IObservable<XDocument>

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have an XML document at a Url "http://test.com/data.xml" which I am currently polling every second

I would like to turn this pooling of an XML source into a IObservable<XDocument>

Comment: Duplicate post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161364/retrieve-xdocument-only-when-modified-using-rx-webrequest-xdocument-load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
    .Select(_ => XDocument.Load("http://test.com/data.xml"));
```

Comment: How could you change the above to only load the XDocument if the "http://test.com/data.xml" file changies. after a http head request that is joined somehow?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161364/retrieve-xdocument-only-when-modified-using-rx-webrequest-xdocument-load

Comment: Publish() is not working with the above pattern this is very important cause i have multiple subscribers

Comment: @MaduAlikor - Can you tell my why it isn't working? Are you calling `.Connect()` on the published observable?